# How to save data from a row in ajax to the database?

Tags: ajax, database, jsp

I have created a table which displays data from the databaseand have given the users the option to add rows to it. I have also added the necessary Ajax script so that whenever users click the button "add" a new row appears at the bottom of the table. 
I am not able to find a way to save the data entered by the user in the newly added row to the database.

```
 `<table border = "1" width = "50%" id="bill">
     <tr>
        <th>Item no</th>
        <th>Product Code</th>
        <th>Dates</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Net Amount</th>
        <th>Tax</th>
        <th>Choose option</th>
     </tr>
     <c:forEach var = "row" items = "${result.rows}">
     <tr>
    <td><c:out value = "${row.Item_no}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value = "${row.Product_Code}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value = "${row.Dates}"/></td>
   <td><c:out value = "${row.Quantity}"/></td>
   <td><c:out value = "${row.Amount}"/></td>
   <td><c:out value="${row.Amount * row.Quantity}"/></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="Tax" value=""></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="gross" value=""></td> 
</tr>
```

' 
`<input type="button" id="addrow" href="#" value="ADD">`//the code to display the table with data from data base along with the add rows option

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var t = $('#bill');
var counter =  $('#bill tr').size() + 1;
console.log(counter);
$('#addrow').on( 'click', function () {
        t.append('<tr width="80%"><td><input type="text" name="Item_No" id="item" value = "" ></td><td><input type="text" name="Product_code" id="pc"></td>\n\
                    <td><input type="text" name="Date" id="date"></td><td><input type="text" name="Quantity" id="quantity"></td>\n\
                    <td><input type="text" name="Amount" id="amount"></td><td><input type="text" name="Net Amount" id="net"></td>\n\
                    <td><input type="text" name="Tax"  id="tax"></td><td><input type="text" name="Gross" id="gross"></td>\n\
                    </tr>');

    counter++;
} ); //The code which displays a new row at the bottom of the table when the users click add option . This is where the user enters his new data and I need to save it to the database.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you will click on `addrow` a new row will append in your table , so there are 2 way you can save value to database .They are as follow :

**1)**. Whenever you append new row ,user will fill inputs to it and then you can create one `submit btn` in your row and i.e :

```
$('#addrow').on( 'click', function () {
        t.append('<tr width="80%">
    <form action="url" method="post">
   <td><input type="text" name="Item_No" id="item" value = "" ></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="Product_code" id="pc"></td>\n\
                       //your input field
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="add to db"><td>
   </form>
   </tr>');
 counter++;
});
```

so,whenever you will click on `submit btn` data will go to `url`provided by you and then you can use ,`request.getParameter("Product_code");` to get values and save values in database .

---

**2)** .You can use ajax ,whenever you append `new row` add a button also to it

```
$('#addrow').on( 'click', function () {
            t.append('<tr width="80%">

       <td><input type="text" name="Item_No" id="item" value = "" ></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="Product_code" id="pc"></td>\n\
                           //your input field
        <td><input type="button" name="submit" id="addtodb" value="add to db"><td>//add this button

       </tr>');
     counter++;
    });
```

When user will `click` on btn you can get all values of input field and then `pass to ajax` and save them in database like below :

```
$('#addtodb').on( 'click', function () {


 var pc=$("#pc").val();//getting value of input field
  var quantity=$("#quantity").val();

 $.ajax({  
            url:"yourclasspageurl",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{ quantity:quantity,pc:pc} //passing data to specified url
            success:function(data){  
                 //do something
            }  
       });  

});
```

Get all , above values same using `request.getParameter("quantity");` and save data to database.

Hope this help you .